# Ubuntu 16: PHP Apache server failing on lamp start

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04

While starting

```
 sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Apache server failing to start?

Comment: any errors for the command?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you simply go to the opt/lampp directory and stop everything, you should be fine:

```
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./lampp stop
```

Then your should see the various pieces stop, with Apache being the last one.
Your problem might be that you are not doing this as root, therefore always use the sudo command as a prefix to anything you do with lammp administration.